# UITABLE view sections with different prototype cells in each section

Tags: swift

I have a table view with different sections and for each section it has different prototype cells. I have created the prototype cell in storyboard but I could not make more than one cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I have attached the whole code for reference.

This is my storyboard design

[image: Screen Shot]

This is the final output screen which it should look like

[image: Screen Shot]

```
    import UIKit

    class PlacePeopleViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var friendlistTableView: UITableView!

        var sectionHead = ["Friends", "Others"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            friendlistTableView.delegate = self
            friendlistTableView.dataSource = self

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }


        // MARK: - tableview datasource & delegate

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return sectionHead.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return self.sectionHead[section]
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if section == 0 {
                return 5
            }else {
                return 10
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! RecentVizzTableViewCell
            cell.placeName.text = "poland"
            cell.placeAddress.text = "Simon Albania"


            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 79
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 15
        }

    }
```

Comment: Use the `section` property of `indexPath` to determine which identifier you need to use. This is table views 101, there should be a ton of resources about this online.

Comment: Exactly. Segregate your logic in terms of `section` and `row` in the `cellForRowAt` method. Also the way I see it, the only difference between is the `connect button`. You need not need two different cells, but rather just one cell and choose to show/hide connect button depending on the section it falls under

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** : You can do this using **only one cell**. just hide/show the **`connect`** Button by checking some condition.

If you want to use **different cells** for **different sections**, inside your `cellForRowAt indexPath` method return your cells based on your section like below .

```
switch  indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1") as! RecentVizzTableViewCellOne
            return cell
        default:
            let defaultcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defaultcell") as! RecentVizzTableViewCellDefatult
            return defaultcell
  }
```

hope this will help to you. good luck.

Comment: please tell me how to add cornerRadius for a button inside the tableview cell.

Comment: inside your cell `yourbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 10`